# Run angular 2 app inside a non-angular app

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I bought a layout to build a web app and then I made a specific part in angular 2. In this web app all the styles come from css files that came with the layout, but, when I add  to a page and try to bootstrap my angular application, it disables all the styles and script in the page. What can I do to make angular to run without messing the styles and scripts that are out of the application?

I'm sorry if I was not so clear.

Comment: I wouldn't try to embed ng2 in another app -- it's suppose to BE the app.

Comment: But I just need a part of the app made in ng2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using twitter bootstrap within my angular project and in my non-angular page I was using too, so, angular was changing all the page style by the twitter bootstrap built in it and all the styles was being missing. After removing the twitter bootstrap built in my angular app, everything became fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Without some more details, I'm not entirely sure. I don't believe Angular.js makes any CSS or styling changes on its own. I would also try to move your bootstrap CSS link above your layout. When your layout css file loads it will overwrite bootstrap's CSS. Thought I am not certain how much of Bootstrap's Javascript will overwrite.